# Sbt - Specify dependency extension

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, artifactory

i have troubles with Sbt.
In my local instance of JFrog Artifactory i have published a java library without the **.pom** file, so i have just the **.jar** file.

**Configuration:**

```
//build.sbt 
libraryDependencies += "com.example" % "my-library" % "1.0" % "provided"


//build.properties
sbt.version = 1.3.0-RC2
```

*Obliviously i have configured the resolvers properly.*

---

Sbt fails with the following error:

```
not found: http://[Artifactory]/artifactory/maven/com/example/my-library/1.0/my-library-1.0.pom
```

The error is clear, indeed **.pom** file doesn't exists.

There is a way to specify, for a specific dependency, the extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for whatever reason you published the jar without a pom file *on purpose*, you can specify an [explicit URL](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Explicit+URL) for the jar you want to depend on, e.g.

```
libraryDependencies += "slinky" % "slinky" % "2.1" 
  from "https://slinky2.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/2.1/slinky.jar"
```

But if you just published the library ivy-style (so an `ivy.xml` file was published instead of a pom file), you just need to specify a right resolver for your repository, which will have [ivy-style patterns](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Resolvers.html#URL).

Answer (score 1):

When publishMavenStyle is true, a POM is generated by the makePom action and published to the repository.

Add this line in your `build.sbt`

```
publishMavenStyle := true
```

**Configuring Artifact Resolution**

To resolve artifacts through Artifactory, simply add the following code snippet to your build.sbt file:

```
resolvers += "Artifactory" at "http://<host>:<port>/artifactory/<repo-key>/"
```

**Deploying Artifacts**

To deploy sbt build artifacts to repositories in Artifactory, add the following code snippets to your build.sbt file.

**For releases, add:**

```
publishTo := Some("Artifactory Realm" at "http://<host>:<port>/artifactory/<repo-key>")
credentials += Credentials("Artifactory Realm", "<host>", "<USERNAME>", "<PASS>")
```

**For snapshots, add:**

```
publishTo := Some("Artifactory Realm" at "http://<host>:<port>/artifactory/<repo-key>;build.timestamp=" + new java.util.Date().getTime)
credentials += Credentials("Artifactory Realm", "<host>", "<USERNAME>", "<PASS>")
```

Where host and port are the host URL and port on which Artifactory is running, and repo-key is the Artifactory repository to which you are deploying artifacts.